# Which denominations regulate how a cross is worn on the body?

Tags: denomination-survey, tradition, symbolism, cross, human-body

In public and private, people wear many different crosses in many manners. Which denominations hold any principles, explicit or implicit, that govern the display of crosses on the body?

Speculating, such rules might require that the cross touch the skin, or that it never be removed, or that it be hung on the neck and not anywhere else on the body, or that it never be worn by certain persons or in certain situations, or that it must be of certain material to carry.

Comment: have you done any research?

Comment: @depperm This is a reformulation of a previous question by the OP.

Comment: @Mick I recognize it, I believe my question is still valid as it says to `Share your research.`

Comment: This is one of those infamous "list questions", making it too broad. Even if it were possible to formulate a list of all denominations which have such rules (it's not--it's not even possible to formulate a list of all denominations), keeping it up to date would be an impossible task.  Would you consider narrowing the question to simply "Are there denominations that regulate how a cross is worn?" or similar? Such an answer could be answered withe a single example, rather than an impossible, exhaustive list.

Comment: @Flimzy well said and I understood, but I wouldn't ask that question. Jehovah's Witnesses don't use crosses --  done.

Comment: @AaronBrick: You could ask "Do any denominations other than JWs...?"  if that's of interest to you.